# MEF Import issue

Tags: import, mef

Import not working.

I have a `UserProfileService` class which I can see as exported in `AggregateCatalog`. `UserProfileService` is in Infrastructure project. I am importing it in `RelayCommand` class which is in Infrastructure project as well. I have gone through similar posts but couldn't solve it. Will appreciate any help. Here is the code:

```
[Export(typeof(IUserProfileService))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class UserProfileService : IUserProfileService
{
    ...
} 

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    [Import]
    private IUserProfileService UserProfileService { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Thanks,
Imad.

Comment: How is the `RelayCommand` object created? Is it imported in a different class? If you're `new`ing it (i.e. creating it manually rather than having MEF create it for you), you will have to call `SatisftImportsOnce` for it to get imported.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adi. Problem is solved.

Comment: You should answer your own question then as it might help others who encounter the same problem.